# I am basing a variable on a spreadsheet column to create PDFs in Google Apps Script. I can't get the variable to assign the correct value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Form, and the results go to a Google Sheet. I wrote a Google Apps Script to create bulk PDFs from the spreadsheet.

There is a checkbox on the form, and the result that goes into the spreadsheet column is

Checked = "Check here if Information is same as above"

Unchecked = "" or NULL (I am not sure which)

This is the javascript to bulk create these PDFs. My problem is that it always comes through on the PDF as ☒, even if there is nothing in that column. I have tried a multitude of way of putting it in different places, using brackets, etc. to no avail. I am a SQL gal, and this is literally the first javascript I have written, so any help is appreciated.

```
function CreateBulkPDFs() {
///////////begin function{

    const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1YAj3MubVRnYUpptEmc92esU0e3vP4KknrgvCO4l9BkI");
    const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1gmCPUmXsl4iwaVWv-7l43-y82cz2ENfF");
    const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1UNHFAlvT5ZMTrIevdsIyf27SgyfO6PQQ");
    const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1oMmL0Wfl9FSFX7_xb4RH-qc2o4qJvhlkNMTKMkwHXB8").getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 49).getDisplayValues();
    //getRange(row start, column start, # of rows, # of columns) 
    var chk;

  let errors = [];
  data.forEach(row => { 
  ///////////begin forEach2( 
   ///////////begin row2{
     try { 
     ///////////begin try{
  if (row[1] !="Success")
  if (row[28] = "Check here if Information is same as above") chk = "☒";
  if (row[28] != "Check here if Information is same as above") chk = "☐";
            CreatePDF(
                row[2],
                row[3],
                row[4],
                row[5],
                row[6],
                row[7],
                row[8],
                row[9],
                row[10],
                row[11],
                row[12],
                row[13],
                row[14],
                row[15],
                row[16],
                row[17],
                row[18],
                row[19],
                row[20],
                row[21],
                row[22],
                row[23],
                row[24],
                row[25],
                row[26],
                row[27],
                //This is Check here if Information is same as above - row[28]
                
                chk,
                
                row[29],
                row[30],
                row[31],
                row[32],
                row[33],
                row[34],
                row[35],
                row[36],
                row[37],
                row[38],
                row[39],
                row[40],
                row[41],
                row[42],
                row[43],
                row[44],
                row[45],
                row[46],
                row[47],
                row[48],
                row[2] + " DOB: " + row[3], /*Name of Document*/
                docFile,
                tempFolder,
                pdfFolder
            );
            errors.push(["Success"]);
        }
     ///////////end try{
catch (err) {
            errors.push(["Failed"]);
        }
       }
   ///////////end row {
    ); 
  ///////////end forEach(
    currentSheet.getRange(2, 2, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).setValues(errors);
}
///////////end function{
```

Comment: I added an additional note to my answer, something that may cause issues depending on what you were going for with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statements are trying to assign a value (`x = y`) to `row[28]` rather than check for equality (`x == y` or in JavaScript, more typically `x === y`).

Try:

```js
if (row[1] !== "Success")
if (row[28] === "Check here if Information is same as above") chk = "☒";
if (row[28] !== "Check here if Information is same as above") chk = "☐";
```

The `===` (rather than `==` as in most other languages) is a particular idiosyncrasy of JavaScript - you [can go down that rabbit hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) if you want, but it's usually safest to default to `===` to ensure you don't get unexpected results.

From the link above:

> The strict equality operator (===) behaves identically to the abstract equality operator (==) except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.
> ...
> The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false. Both are equally quick.

**Edit to add**:

There may be an additional issue depending on your intention with the line `if (row[1] !== "Success")` that could give you confusing results - currently this condition will *only* apply to the line directly below (`if (row[28] === "Check  ...`), but not the following line. In pseudocode that would look like:

```
if (x)
this line will execute conditionally
this line will not
```

So you might either want to remove it if it isn't necessary, or explicitly enclose the statements you want to execute conditionally within brackets

```js
if (row[1] !== "Success") {
  if (row[28] === "Check here if Information is same as above") chk = "☒";
  if (row[28] !== "Check here if Information is same as above") chk = "☐";
}
```